# How to allow cross origin request with java spring

Tags: java, spring

I have tried everything. i dont know how to do it. it just doesent work.

I have added "@CrossOrigin" / "@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)" practicaly everywere.

how do i configure java spring to allow cross-origin requests?

This is how my request looks like

```
   $.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: "http://localhost:80/adData",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (responseSchools) {
       //stuff
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        //stuff
    }
});
```

Code of Java app

```
  @GetMapping
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = AD_DATA_ENDPOINT)
    public String getAdData() {
        return "wuwuwu";
    }
```

Comment: In my case I want to apply cross origin on all GET method and I followed `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods = { RequestMethod.GET }, allowedHeaders = "*")` at class level. It worked for me. Annotation what you are using is fine and should work. Do you have code in public repo so I can execute on my local?

Comment: you have to specify the `origins` parameter or its alias `value`; see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CrossOrigin.html

Comment: @ShaunakPatel Sadly that doesn't work either. Is it possible that there is a problem with the client?

Comment: Client? Are you referring to rest tool like postman or Nodejs application? This does not required any changes on client. Given annotation just set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials and Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather pedestrian, but working approach is to overwrite the header from within the handling method:

```
 // remember to add an `HttpServletResponse response` parameter 
 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

This however is a per-handler solution. On the bright side, it works for any and all headers: whatever Spring was going to do for you, you can always overwrite it in the handler itself.

Comment: I dont realy have a refrence to a "response" object. How would that work?

Comment: You just add it as another parameter to your handler method. See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments. In your case, `getAdData(HttpServletResponse response)`

Comment: This kind of works. I don't get the Cross-origin request not allowed error anymore. but the request still fails. (althou this is probably a completly different problem)

Comment: Look for the exact error message in the server's log, and if you can't find what is wrong on your own, ask another question.

Comment: Soooooo... I checkde the {request.responseText} in the error function of the js. and it actualy has the proper response in it^^ wtf why does is fail then if i do get the response im after(just in the error code)?

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot for this I found the solution for this:

There is no problem in the code, since you are using `Cross Origin` request it first sent `OPTIONS` request to the server. In order to fix this I added following piece of code in my server configuration section:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
```

Also create a file with following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
   @Override
   public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
       registry.addMapping("/**");
   }
}
```

I am sure this will solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, most servers allow `GET` requests from everywhere. Second, there are multiple ways of handling CORS requests on your server.

- `@CrossOrigin` annotation (which allows `GET`, `HEAD` a d `POST` methods by default) can be placed on your Controllers or your Controller Class.
- A `CORS Filter` can be used which will allow `OPTIONS` requests.
- Using `WebMvConfigurer`, you can specify your configuration.

Find more details here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 0):

Add below maven dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thetransactioncompany/cors-filter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And add below line into **web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

this solves my problem.